# Python, replace all occurrences of the pattern in a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, replace

I need to write a program that replaces all inputted values in a string. Thus: the string reads as "[link1], [link2], [link3]", the input is "1, 2", I want to replace both [link1] and [link2] with another text.

I've tried both replace() and re.sub, but these expectedly only change the first occurrence of the pattern. What am I doing wrong?

```
    for i in input:
    output = string.replace(f'[link{i}]', '')
    # output = re.sub(f'[link{i}]', '', string)
    return output
```

Comment: call `replace` multiple times if you want to replace multiple strings

Comment: Can't you concatenate the options `1` and `2` into a pattern that would look like `link[12]` which would then match both `link1` and `link2` using `re.sub`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are not saving the modified string. It is just changing the raw string every time and saving only one change.
Try like this:

```
string = "[link1], [link2], [link3]"

INPUT = input('Give the input').split(',')

replacer = {'1' : 'ONE', "2" : 'Two', '3' : 'Three'}

for i in INPUT:
    string = string.replace(f'[link{i}]', replacer[i])
    
print(string)
```